# Add a hidden tag to outgoing mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I create a mail by VBA when sending invoices and automated newsletters by Outlook (2019).

For reimporting the mails from the Sent folder into the database it would be convenient to read a hidden tag including the customer number which I would like to embed into the mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom property either using `MailItem.UserProperties.Add` or by setting your custom property directly using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`.

Keep in mind adding a user property can force Outlook to send in the RTF format (the infamous winmail.dat attachment), so the latter solution is preferable. You just need to make sure you get the DASL property name (to be used with `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`) right. You can use the former approach (`MailItem.UserProperties.Add`), take a look at the message in the Sent Items folder with [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author - click IMessage button), then use the DASL property name replacing `MailItem.UserProperties.Add` with `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`